# Increase memory size in R 4.3.1 with RStudio 2023.06.02

Tags: r, rstudio

I have 64GB of RAM on a Windows computer running R 4.3.1 with RStudio 2023.06.02. I would like to use as much memory as possible to run programs in RStudio. Currently RStudio uses no more than ~13% CPU and ~6% Memory as seen in Task Manager. I have tried the following.

In Windows PowerShell:

```
Add-Content c:\Users\$env:USERNAME\Documents\.Renviron "R_MAX_VSIZE=50Gb"
Add-Content c:\Users\$env:USERNAME\Documents\.Renviron "R_MAX_MEM_SIZE=50Gb"
```

Added to the .Renviron:

```
file.edit(file.path("~", ".Rprofile"))
invisible(utils::memory.limit(size = 50000))
```

In cmd:

```
cd C:\Program Files\RStudio\
start rstudio.exe --max-mem-size=50GB
```

When starting from cmd I get

> Warning message: 'memory.limit()' is no longer supported

Nothing works. Anything else I can try?

Comment: R doesn't really use a memory limit any more by default. It just just use as much RAM as it needs. What makes you think it should be using more RAM? It doesn't help anything if R asks for more RAM but doesn't actually do anything with it.

Comment: From `?memory.limit`: *"Report on Memory Allocation (no longer supported)"*.

Comment: RStudio shouldn't be using much CPU/RAM, it's only an interface to R. Any work that R is doing will show up as its own process separate from RStudio

Comment: @SeñorO I don't even see R as a process in the Task Manager! Am I missing something?

Comment: @MrFlick I would like this program (bkmr) to run faster and assumed the run was slow because of using limited RAM. So it might be that the RAM is not the limiting factor? Any idea if I can use a different approach then?

Comment: 13% CPU across the cores, or in 1 core? Assuming that you have an 8-core CPU, it could be that R is throttled by the CPU. Note that R is single threaded, and to leverage across the cores, you'd have to do some parallelization.  https://towardsdatascience.com/getting-started-with-parallel-programming-in-r-d5f801d43745